# From the Active Directory Snap-In, how can I find the GUID for a user?

Tags: active-directory, user

How ca I view the GUID associated with an Active Directory user under windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PsGetSid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897417.aspx) may do it.

Comment: FYI, this command return only the `SID` and not the `ObjectGUID` as requested. Strange it has been accepted.

Comment: Agreed, PsGetSid does not provide the AD Guid.

Answer (score 24):

This is easy to do using `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

Click `View` > `Advanced Features` (to be able to see `Attribute Editor` tab later)

Drill down to the user you want to know about and open the `Properties`.

Click the `Attribute Editor` tab

Scroll down to the "ObjectSID" or "ObjectGUID" attributes.

Profit.

Answer (score 3):

Open powershell.

Type: `get-aduser -identity <insert username here>`

The `ObjectGUID` will appear in the output

Comment: Depending on the operating system version, you will have to install "Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) for Windows" to get the command.
Some other answers give the way to get the `SID` and not the `ObjectGUID`. A link to get the difference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/security-identifiers#security-identifiers-and-globally-unique-identifiers

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [ADSI Edit snap-in](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(v=ws.10).aspx) for the Microsoft Management Console. See [Using ADSI Edit on WIN-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616099/using-adsi-edit-on-win-7).

The GUID is in an Active Directory attribute called [objectguid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679021(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

c:\windows\system32\LDP.exe

Connection -> Bind -> OK

Browse -> Search

Base DN :  (this varies per environment)

Fitler: (samAccountName=yourAccountName)

Scope: Subtree (this does nested search)

Attributes :  add "objectGUID"

...

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell type the following commands:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties SID | where {$_.sid -eq 'number here'}

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties SID | where {$_.sid -eq 'number here'}
```